# Disable ListBoxFor in knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I create a listbox in asp.net MVC using razor view engine. For client side, I use knockout.js.

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(
    x => x.SelectedOutletBrandIds,
    new SelectListItem[0],
    new
    {
        @class = "outlet-brand-select",
        data_bind = "options: outletBrands, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', selectedOptions: selectedOutletBrandIds"
    })
```

I would like to disable this list box from knockout.js in client side. How can I do this?

When I set "disabled" attribute in SelectedOutletBrandIds drop down, it is not still working.

```
$('#SelectedOutletBrandIds').prop('disabled', true);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZmzW.png)

Comment: Not related but remove the pointless `multiple = string.Empty,`.

Comment: thanks for pointing me

Comment: And to disable it, you can use `$('#SelectedOutletBrandIds').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke It is not working.

Comment: Works fine for me :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke textbox is dsiabled. But drop down is still enabled.

Comment: What textbox and what dropdown? `@Html.ListBoxFor()` generates a listbox (`<select multiple="multiple">`)!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my question. please have a look at this.

Comment: Your image suggest you using a jquery plugin for the `<select>` - show the relevant code!

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is not jquery plugin. It is rendered as listbox in Razor view engine.

Comment: That is not what your image shows (that is not a standard html `<select multiple="multiple">` tag. And here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gceowdum/) to prove it works